# I want SQLplus count(*) to return zero-values

Tags: sql, count

I'm using Oracle 10.2 and have the following query:

```
    select h.company, count(*)  
    from history h 
    where h.status = '2'  
    and h.substatus = '0'  
    and h.timestamp > '2012-01-01'  
    and h.timestamp < '2012-02-01'  
    group by h.company
    having (h.company = 'AAA')  
    or (h.company = 'BBB')  
    or (h.company = 'CCC')  
    order by h.company
```

This will count the amount of times any customer from the companies AAA, BBB or CCC has reached a specific point (status = 2).
Presume no (zero) customers from BBB did so, the result will come back with 2 rows of count(AAA and CCC).

What I want: I wish for the query to return me rows for all 3 companies, even tho the count is zero.

Sorry for the odd layout of the query. It's made to work with MS Excel as well.

Edit: Sorry.. Too little caffeine. changed "Customer" in the later half of the query to "Company".

Clarification: A customer is made unique by combining "h.company" and "h.customer" (or by using the same method in customer-table (customer c), like "c.company" and "c.customer"

Edit 2: Updated code.

```
    select c.company, count(*)
    from companyregister c
    left join history h on h.company = c.company
    where h.status = '2'
    and h.substatus = '0'
    and h.timestamp > '2012-01-01'
    and h.timestamp < '2012-02-01'
    group by c.company
    having (c.company = 'AAA')
    or (c.company = 'BBB')
    or (c.company = 'CCC')
    order by c.company
```

Both sets of code from above will yield two rows as follows:
AAA  630
CCC 3020

I would like to have BBB represented, but since they have zero rows in history, they don't show.

Comment: Made a few errors in the query. Changed "customer" to "company. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a left join on the customer table. I don't know what you have named it, but like this:

```
select c.company, count(h.customer)
from customer as  c
left join history as h on h.customer = c.customer
...
```

Another alternative is to use a condition when counting. I'm not sure if there is any other condition that you need along with the status, but something liket this:

```
select company, sum(case status when '2' then 1 else 0 end)  
from history
where substatus = '0'
and timestamp > '2012-01-01'
and timestamp < '2012-02-01'
and customer in ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
group by customer  
order by customer
```

Comment: `count(*)` will count incorrect values (especially it will return `1` for those customers that are not in the history. It should be `count(h.customer)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, you are of course right. I forgot that when writing the answer, I have corrected it now. :)

Comment: I used the code you provided, but had to try some alterations since I provided a query with a few errors in my post.

Comment: @Guffa - I got the query to run, but it still wont show companies with no entries in history. I get amounts for company AAA and CCC, but BBB is not listed (as they had zero customers).

Comment: @Numpus: Which version are you using? Can you add the current query that you are using in an edit in your question?

Comment: @Guffa: Updated post with current code at the bottom. Both sets of code returns the same result. I'm using Oracle SQLplus 10.2 (DB is 10.2 as well).

Comment: @Numpus: Use `count(h.company)` instead of `count(*)`, and move the conditions from the `where` to the `on` in the join.